# Easy OCR Library Does Not Work

Tags: java, android, ocr

This is my first Android App project and I am trying to apply OCR function in my Android App by using Easy OCR library made by [Priyank Verma](https://priyankvex.wordpress.com/2015/09/02/making-an-ocr-app-for-android-using-tesseract/)'s [Easy OCR Library](https://github.com/priyankvex/Easy-Ocr-Scanner-Android) as it is the most simplified & most recent OCR library I can get on. But I think the creator of that library wont answer people's query in his own blog, so I try to ask here. If this is not a good question, I will delete it.

So here's the problem, I have an app with four tabs and in one of the tabs, I tried to use the library example which I try to apply them in my tab. In that tab, there's a 'Scan' button that will take a picture, save it and then scan it. After that, it should return output of text characters from the scanning process. And the execution of the app successfully return with zero error.

But the problem here is, it failed to save the picture by which it will lead the failure of the scanning process thus returning nothing. I can't see any problem here, maybe someone with sharp eyes can detect them?

### **||||| UPDATE 1 |||||**

I have set breakpoints as suggested by [Ishita Sinha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935423/easy-ocr-library-does-not-work?noredirect=1#comment63334347_37935423) and I have found out the file did save, it just saved on different directory which is on my internal storage (*/storage/emulated/0/EasyOcrScanner* or *internal storage/EasyOcrScanner*). The real conflict occur here is when after the image have been saved, which is scanning of the image. Still, I can't figure out why is that. I have marked '***%%***' in the ***FileUtils Java*** and ***EasyOCRScanner Java*** to show what I have found. I need some assist on how to successfully scan after the image has been saved.

### **||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||**

### **||||| UPDATE 2 |||||**

I have pushed my project on GitHub as requested by [Anand Savjani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935423/easy-ocr-library-does-not-work?noredirect=1#comment63394322_37935423). You guys can check there. The project name is 'Queue-App'.

https://github.com/Kaydarin/Queue-App

### **||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||**

**---------- From My App's Tab ----------**

**My App's Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kaydarinapp.queueappv2">
    <!-- Save file permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- Read file permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Camera permission -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <!-- Internet permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**My Tab's XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Tab2"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="8pt"
        />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Scan"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**My Tab Java**

```
package com.kaydarinapp.queueappv2;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo.Config;
import com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo.EasyOcrScanner;
import com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo.EasyOcrScannerListener;

/**
 * Created by Kaydarin on 6/1/2016.
 */

//Our class extending fragment
public class Tab2 extends Fragment implements EasyOcrScannerListener {

    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private FragmentActivity fragActivity;
    EasyOcrScanner mEasyOcrScanner;
    TextView textView;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    Button btnCapture;

    //Overriden method onCreateView
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragActivity = super.getActivity();
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);

        textView = (TextView) fragActivity.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        // initialize EasyOcrScanner instance.
        mEasyOcrScanner = new EasyOcrScanner(getActivity(), "EasyOcrScanner",
                Config.REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE, "eng");

        // Set ocrScannerListener
        mEasyOcrScanner.setOcrScannerListener(this);

        btnCapture = (Button) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mEasyOcrScanner.takePicture();
            }
        });

        return linearLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Call onImageTaken() in onActivityResult.
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && requestCode == Config.REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE){
            mEasyOcrScanner.onImageTaken();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback when after taking picture, scanning process starts.
     * Good place to show a progress dialog.
     * @param filePath file path of the image file being processed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onOcrScanStarted(String filePath) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Scanning...");
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Callback when scanning is finished.
     * Good place to hide teh progress dialog.
     * @param bitmap Bitmap of image that was scanned.
     * @param recognizedText Scanned text.
     */
    @Override
    public void onOcrScanFinished(Bitmap bitmap, String recognizedText) {
        textView.setText(recognizedText);
        if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()){
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

**---------- From Easy OCR Library ----------**

**Easy OCR Library's Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscanner">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

</manifest>
```

**Config Java**

```
package com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo;

/**
 * Created by Priyank(@priyankvex) on 27/8/15.
 */
public class Config {

    public static String TAG = "OcrScanner";
    public static int REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE = 1995;

}
```

**EasyOCRScannerListener Java**

```
package com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

/**
 * Created by Priyank(@priyankvex) on 27/8/15.
 *
 * Interface for the callbacks for {@link EasyOcrScanner}.
 */
public interface EasyOcrScannerListener {

    public void onOcrScanStarted(String filePath);

    public void onOcrScanFinished(Bitmap bitmap, String recognizedText);
}
```

**EasyOCRScanner Java**

```
package com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by Priyank(@priyankvex) on 27/8/15.
 *
 * Class to handle scanning of image.
 */
public class EasyOcrScanner {

    protected Activity mActivity;
    private String directoryPathOriginal;
    private String filePathOriginal;
    private int requestCode;
    private EasyOcrScannerListener mOcrScannerListener;
    private String trainedDataCode;

    public EasyOcrScanner(Activity activity, String directoryPath, int requestCode, String trainedDataCode){
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.directoryPathOriginal = directoryPath;
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
        this.trainedDataCode = trainedDataCode;
    }

    public void takePicture(){
        Intent e = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        this.filePathOriginal = FileUtils.getDirectory(this.directoryPathOriginal) + File.separator + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg";
        e.putExtra("output", Uri.fromFile(new File(this.filePathOriginal)));

        startActivity(e);
    } // %%%%%%%%%%%% POSITIVE BREAKPOINT: AFTER THIS POINT, THE APP DOES NOT APPEAR TO SCAN THE CAPTURED IMAGE AS IT RETURN BACK TO THE APP WITHOUT ANY SCANNED TEXT OUTPUT %%%%%%%%%%%%

    public void onImageTaken(){
        Log.d(Config.TAG, "onImageTaken with path " + this.filePathOriginal);
        ImageProcessingThread thread = new ImageProcessingThread(this.mOcrScannerListener,
                this.filePathOriginal, this.directoryPathOriginal, this.mActivity, this.trainedDataCode);
        thread.execute();
    }

    private void startActivity(Intent intent){
        if(this.mActivity != null) {
            this.mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, this.requestCode);
        }
    }

    public void setOcrScannerListener(EasyOcrScannerListener mOcrScannerListener) {
        this.mOcrScannerListener = mOcrScannerListener;
    }


}
```

**FileUtils Java**

```
package com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by Priyank(@priyankvex) on 27/8/15.
 */
public class FileUtils {

    public static String getDirectory(String folderName) {
        File directory = null;
        directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + folderName);
        if(!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }

        return directory.getAbsolutePath(); // %%%%%%%%%%%% POSITIVE BREAKPOINT: IT SHOWS THAT THE FILE DIRECTORY SAVED IN INTERNAL STORAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%
    }

    public static String getTessdataDirectory(String directoryPath){
        File tessdataDirectory = new File(directoryPath + "/tessdata");
        if (tessdataDirectory.mkdirs()){
            Log.d(Config.TAG, "tessdata directory created");
        }
        return tessdataDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

**ImageProcessingThread Java**

```
package com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
 * Created by Priyank(@priyankvex) on 27/8/15.
 *
 * Async Task to process the image and scan the image using tesseract library.
 * Equipped with proper callbacks.
 */
public class ImageProcessingThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private EasyOcrScannerListener mOcrScannerListener;
    private String filePath;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private String scannedText;
    // trained data file used by Tesseract will be copied in directoryPath/tessdata
    private String directoryPath;
    private String absoluteDirectoryPath;
    private Activity mActivity;
    String trainedDataCode;

    public ImageProcessingThread(EasyOcrScannerListener ocrScannerListener, String filePath,
                                 String directoryPath, Activity activity, String trainedDataCode) {
        this.mOcrScannerListener = ocrScannerListener;
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.directoryPath = directoryPath;
        this.absoluteDirectoryPath = FileUtils.getDirectory(this.directoryPath);
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.trainedDataCode = trainedDataCode;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mOcrScannerListener.onOcrScanStarted(this.filePath);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        processImage();
        makeTessdataReady();
        scannedText = scanImage();
        Log.d(Config.TAG, "Scanned test : " + scannedText);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        mOcrScannerListener.onOcrScanFinished(mBitmap, scannedText);
    }

    private void processImage() {
        int imageOrientationCode = getImageOrientation();
        Bitmap rawBitmap = getBitmapFromPath();
        // Getting the bitmap in right orientation.
        this.mBitmap = rotateBitmap(rawBitmap, imageOrientationCode);
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromPath() {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 4;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.filePath, bmOptions);
        return bitmap;
    }

    private int getImageOrientation() {
        ExifInterface exif = null;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(this.filePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        assert exif != null;
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
        return orientation;
    }

    private Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation){

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                return bitmap;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                break;
            default:
                return bitmap;
        }
        try {
            Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            bitmap.recycle();
            return bmRotated;
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private String scanImage(){
        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        Log.d(Config.TAG, "Data path : " + FileUtils.getDirectory(this.directoryPath));
        baseApi.init(FileUtils.getDirectory(this.directoryPath) + "/", this.trainedDataCode);
        baseApi.setImage(this.mBitmap);
        String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
        baseApi.end();

        return recognizedText;
    }

    private void makeTessdataReady(){

        // created tessdata directory if necessary under absoluteDirectoryPath and returns its absolute path.
        String tessdirectoryPath = FileUtils.getTessdataDirectory(this.absoluteDirectoryPath);

        if (!(new File(tessdirectoryPath+ "/" + this.trainedDataCode + ".traineddata")).exists()) {
            try {

                AssetManager assetManager = mActivity.getAssets();
                InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/" + this.trainedDataCode + ".traineddata");
                //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                // Output stream with the location where we have to write the eng.traineddata file.
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tessdirectoryPath + "/"  + this.trainedDataCode
                        + ".traineddata");

                // Transfer bytes from in to out
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                //gin.close();
                out.close();

                Log.v(Config.TAG, "Copied " + " traineddata");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(Config.TAG, "Was unable to copy " + " traineddata " + e.toString());
            }
        }
        else{
            Log.d(Config.TAG, "tessdata already present");
        }
    }

}
```

Hope someone can me help here. Really appreciate it.....

Comment: Have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    ` in your manifest?

Comment: @IshitaSinha It already included in the Easy OCR library's manifest. Should I include it in my app's manifest?

Comment: Yes, please include it in your app's manifest as well and check if the error persists.

Comment: @IshitaSinha Still run with no error and failed to save the image file...

Comment: In your `EasyOcrScanner#takePicture()`, you're calling `startActivity(e)`. Don't you need to call `startActivityForResult`? I'm sorry I'm being hasty right now. I'll look through your code more thoroughly when I get some time. Meanwhile, please check if you need to call `startActivity` or `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: @IshitaSinha I have tried change `startActivity(e)` to `this.mActivity.startActivityForResult(e, this.requestCode)`, still same... No worries, mine can be wait atleast for few days... >.<

Comment: Your code seems fine. I have no idea why the image is not getting saved. I'm really sorry I couldn't help. Maybe you could print logs or set breakpoints to check whether the file path is correct, etc?

Comment: @IshitaSinha It's okay... I'll try do that... Anyway, thank you for the assist...

Comment: Please try this one http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/ Hope it will helpful for you

Comment: @IshitaSinha I have tried what you have told me, it seems that the image saved in different directory. The real problem is that it does not seem to scan right after the image has been saved. It supposed to work but I don't understand why.

Comment: @AnandSavjani Thank you for that but I have tried from those guides and I have a hard time applying it into my project as mine have fragments (tabs)... The only useful to me from that guide is from the comment about setup the library... Plus it is quite outdated I guess...

Comment: @Kaydarin : Please post your code over github when you implement ocr with this updated library so we can use your code easily.

Comment: @AnandSavjani As requested, I have pushed my project on GitHub... You can refer on the link that I have posted in my question above.

Comment: Please rename your project name . So anyone can easily search by name in google or github. Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: @AnandSavjani I have rename my project to 'Queue-App'.. Is it alright? because I don't even know what people search these days....

Comment: I'm still unable to find anything that will help you. Could you contact the author through his email address? (priyankvex95[AT]gmail[DOT]com)

Comment: @IshitaSinha done... I hope my email get the respond...

Comment: @Kaydarin : Not an issue. I will use your code